# Change date and week number to a range of dates and week number column

Tags: powerbi

I have a table like this in Power-BI.

TableA

```
Date   Weeknumber
1/22/2016   4
1/23/2016   4
1/24/2016   4
1/25/2016   5
1/26/2016   5
1/27/2016   5
1/28/2016   5
1/29/2016   5
1/30/2016   5
1/31/2016   5
2/1/2016    6
2/2/2016    6
2/3/2016    6
2/4/2016    6
2/5/2016    6
2/6/2016    6
2/7/2016    6
```

I would like to convert this to a table like this,

```
DateRange               WeekNumber
1/22/2016 - 1/4/2016      4
1/25/2016 - 1/31/2016     5
2/1/2016  - 2/7/2016      6
```

How can we transform this data using M Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `Weeknumber` and use both min and max as aggregations on the `Date` column so that your resulting table would be

| Weeknumber | MinDate | MaxDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1/22/2016 | 1/24/2016 |
| 5 | 1/25/2016 | 1/31/2016 |
| 6 | 2/01/2016 | 2/07/2016 |

From there you can define your `DateRange` column by concatenating `MinDate` and `MaxDate`.